# jsTree load nodes from custom function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree

I'm using [jsTree](http://www.jstree.com/) plugin to build tree of custom items. I know how to load items via ajax requests, but in my case I have nodes in variable `m_items` which is Array type. When node is expanding I need to return only part of items from `m_items`, so I need some way to load subnodes with custom function which accepts expandable node and which will return a array of nodes.

I think that there is at least one way to resolve it, but it is a custom way: initialy loads root level and one level of each subnode. When any node is opened, then loads next level of node. But this way has at least one leak: loads too much unnecessary items. So I'm searching some built-in functionality.

Answer (score 2):

It's an interesting problem, however if your target browsers are up to date browsers, excluding < IE9, this should work :

```
var TreeHelper = function(items, limit, start) {
    this.items_ = items || [];
    this.limit = limit || 5;
    this.start = start || 0;
}

TreeHelper.prototype = {
    push: function(item) {
        this.items_.push(item);
        return this;
    }
};

Object.defineProperty(TreeHelper.prototype, 'items', {
    get: function() {
        return this.items_.slice(this.start, this.limit);
    }
});

var helper = new TreeHelper([item1, item2, item3, ...], 5, 0);
......
function_that_needs_m_Items(helper.items);
```